# Spring Security seems to be ignoring a certain service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement Method Security using @PreAuthorize.

Spring Version: 4.2.3.Release
Spring Security: 4.0.3.Release

I have implemented a CustomPermissionEvaluator. I have noticed that it seems to be working fine except for 1 service where the hasPmerission is not called.
I know this because I get the a logging message from hasPermission / or in the erroneous case do not get the log:

```
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object o, Object o1) {
    logger.info("Call to hasPermission with "+o+" and "+o1);
...
}
```

My Spring configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class RootConfiguration {
}
```

MVC Config

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"OntoRais.*"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigIn()     {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}


@Bean(name="multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(50000000);
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}
}
```

Method Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends       GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

@Autowired
private CustomPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator;

@Override
protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler
            = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    handler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
    return handler;
}


public CustomPermissionEvaluator getPermissionEvaluator() {
    return permissionEvaluator;
}

public void setPermissionEvaluator(CustomPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator) {
    this.permissionEvaluator = permissionEvaluator;
}
}
```

Initializer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class MessageWebApplicationInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.addListener(org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener.class);
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { MvcConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

    return new Filter[]{new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(),
            new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter(),
            new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")
    };
}
}
```

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
OntoRAISUserDetailsService ontoRAISUserDetailsService;


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
            formLogin().
            and().
            logout().
            and().
            authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers("/login").permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().
            and().csrf().disable();

}

@Autowired
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(ontoRAISUserDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(ontoRAISUserDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}


@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

public OntoRAISUserDetailsService getOntoRAISUserDetailsService() {
    return ontoRAISUserDetailsService;
}

public void setOntoRAISUserDetailsService(OntoRAISUserDetailsService ontoRAISUserDetailsService) {
    this.ontoRAISUserDetailsService = ontoRAISUserDetailsService;
}
```

The Service in question:

```
@Service
public class StakeholderService {

@Autowired
private OntopManager om;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("OntoRais");

public OntopManager getOm() {
    return om;
}

public void setOm(OntopManager om) {
    this.om = om;
}

@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#stakeholderType, 'Create_StakeholderType')")
public void createStakeholderType(StakeholderType stakeholderType) {
    try {
        logger.info("Create stakeholder type in service layer");
        List<OBDADataSource> sources = om.getObdaModel().getSources();
        OBDAMappingAxiom mapping = om.getObdaModel().getMapping(new URI("genertatedURI"), MappingList.StakheholderType());

        HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("stakeholderName", stakeholderType.getLabel());

        String query = ClassSQLHelper.generateSQLCreateSatement(mapping.getSourceQuery(), values);
        SQLHelper.executeSQL(query, sources.get(0));

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And the controller from which i call the service layer:

```
@Api(description = "Operations related to Stakeholders")
@RestController
public class StakeholderController {

@Autowired
private OntopManager om;

@Autowired
StakeholderService stakeholderService;

@Autowired
ProjectService projectService;

private static final Logger logger =     LoggerFactory.getLogger("OntoRais");

...

 /**
 * Add a new Stakeholder Type
 *
 * @param stakeholdertype The new Stakeholder to be added.
 * @return
 */
@ApiOperation(value = "Add new stakeholder type",
        notes = "",
        response = ResponseResource.class,
        responseContainer = "Object")
@JsonView(Views.Details.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/stakeholder/types", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<List<StakeholderType>> addStakeholderType(@RequestBody StakeholderType stakeholdertype) {
    logger.info("Add Stakeholder type in controller");
    getStakeholderService().createStakeholderType(stakeholdertype);
    return getStakeholderTypes();
}
```

When calling api/stakeholder/types" with method = POST
This is my debug output:

```
Add Stakeholder type in controller 
Create stakeholder type in service layer 
INSERT INTO prefix_http_www_ontorais_de_stakeholdertype(id,stakeholderName) VALUES(DEFAULT,'TESTEWRTERETE');
```

As you can see the log from hasPermission is not present -> not called.
I can see that the method is called from my other method sercurity annotations in other service objects.

A similar Service which correctly invokes hasPermission as expected just for comparison:

```
@Service
public class OrganisationService {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("OntoRais");
@Autowired
private OntopManager om;

@Autowired
private ProjectService projectService;

...

@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('Add_Organisation')")
public void addOrganisation(Organisation organisation) {
    List<OBDADataSource> sources = om.getObdaModel().getSources();

    OBDAMappingAxiom mapping = null;
    try {
        mapping = om.getObdaModel().getMapping(new URI("genertatedURI"), MappingList.OrganisationMapping());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
    valueMap.put("organisationName", organisation.getName());
    valueMap.put("organisationDescription", organisation.getDescription());

    String query = ClassSQLHelper.generateSQLCreateSatement(mapping.getSourceQuery(), valueMap);

    SQLHelper.executeSQL(query, sources.get(0));
}
```

Any hints on what I am doing wrong/missing/am blind for are very welcome thanks.

Benedict

Comment: `OntoRais.*` is not a valid package name. `StakeholderService` does not implement an interface, so in order for `@PreAuthorize` to work a library like cglib or javassist has to be included. What is the difference between your services?

Comment: Ok changed my Component scan to `@ComponentScan({"OntoRais.api",
        "OntoRais.datalayer.database.service",
        "OntoRais.security",
        "OntoRais.datalayer.ontology.ontop",
        "OntoRais.datalayer.ontology.service",
        "OntoRais.config"
})`.  None ogf my services implement an interface. Shouldn't the problem occure in all my services? 
I can not find any difference in the services. I will include a working service in the original question just to be sure.

Comment: If no service implements an interface then the problem is something else, of course. I think `@ComponentScan({"OntoRais"})` should be enough. In `StakeholderController`, what's the code for `getStakeholderService()`? If it doesn't return the secured proxy, that would be the problem. You can add a breakpoint in your service method and look at the call stack.

Comment: In `getStakeholderService()`  I simply return the local instance of the service which is @Autowired

Comment: I have read in several different locations, that it is important where you put your `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`  Could this be a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Ok narrowed the problem down: i found this message in my log: 
[class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 

Now to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, and a solution.

The Problem was that my CustomPermissionEvaluator depended on a method within the StakeholderService. Even though that method was not secured this resulted in the Spring not being able to proxy the object, therefore preventing any security checks.

Even though it is a bad idea to use a service layer object in the PermissionEvaluator, perhaps someone could elaborate on the exact implications, as i am definately not an expert in spring sercurity